# Taylor series expansion of $\frac{(1+x)}{1}+\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{3}}{3}+\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{5}}{5}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I wanted to find the Taylor expansion of the summation:

$\dfrac{(1+x)}{1}+\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/3}}{3}+\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/5}}{5}+\cdots$
.

I can't evaluate it normally using the first derivative, second derivative... method since the summation terms don't equal $0$ when $x=0$

So I broke down the terms individually, $(1+x)^\frac{1}{3}=a_0+a_1x^1+\cdots=$ and $(1+x)^\frac{1}{5}=b_0+b_1x^1+\cdots$

However this procedure is tedious and requires a lot of summations for each $x^n$ term. Is there a better way of evaluating the Taylor series?

Comment: The derivative of the summation is equivalent to a variation of the Basel problem when $x=0$. Could the resulting Taylor series be a trigonometric function somehow?

Comment: I'm not convinced this even converges.

Comment: Yes for most cases it doesn't, but even ln(1-x) doesn't right? Is there a criteria to exclude certain summations?

Comment: Uhm, for $-1\le x<1$ the series $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n$ converges (and equals $\ln(1-x)$)

Comment: What is the value of your sum at $x=0$?

Comment: For $x \ge 0$, your sum is greater than $1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} +  \ldots  =  + \infty$. For $-1<x<0$, it is greater than $(1 + x)\left( {1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} +  \ldots } \right) =  + \infty$. For $x=-1$, it is $0$.

Comment: Ohh thank you for clarifying. Does the summation converge when x is between -1 and -2?

Comment: @SoapEatr Define $(-1)^{1/3}$, etc.

Comment: For $x<-1$ let's use the real roots: $$(1+x)^{1/(2k+1)} := -(-1-x)^{1/(2k+1)}$$Then use the same arguments as before to get value $-\infty$.

Comment: The problem with this function is the infinite constant. We can improvise a bit :) and consider a regularised function instead:
$$f_{reg}(x)=\dfrac{(1+x)-1}{1}+\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/3}-1}{3}+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/2k+1}-1}{2k+1}$$
which is well defined for $x\in(-1;\infty)$. At $x\to0$
$$f_{reg}(x)=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}x+\left(\frac34\zeta(3)-\frac12\zeta(2)\right)\frac{x^2}2+...$$
At $x\to\infty$
$$f_{reg}(x)=x+\frac1{3^2}x^{-2/3}+\frac1{5^2}x^{-4/5}+...$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying :) I don't know too much mathematics apart from high school stuff. Certainly a very interesting result you evaluated:) 

If I alter the initial summation to

$\dfrac{(1+x)}{1}-\dfrac{(1+x)^{-1/3}}{3}+\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/5}}{5}-\dfrac{(1+x)^{-1/7}}{7}+\cdots$

Can the summation be represented as a Taylor series?

Comment: This function is also well defined at $x\in(-1;\infty)$. At $x=0$
$$g(0)=1-\frac13+\frac15-...=\beta(1)=\frac\pi4$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function
At $x\to0$
$$g(x)=\frac\pi4+\frac{\zeta(2)}2+O(x^2)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav It should be $\frac{\zeta(2)}{2} x$.

Comment: @Gary, thank you! Yes, $g(x)=\frac\pi4+\frac{\zeta(2)}2x+O(x^2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)